# How to get the index of an item in a mongo result set

Tags: mongodb

I want to perform a sorted query on a mongodb collection, find an specific item and retrieve its index in the resultset.
For example, find all students, sort by grade in descending order and get the position of student 'John Connor'. Like getting the ranking of John Connor in the class.
The only way that comes to my mind is querying the whole collection and programmatically performing a search on the resultset. It doesn't look efficient at all, specially because it may have memory issues when collections grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large data sets one answer for this class of problem is to calculate the ranking periodically - once a day, once an hour, whatever fits your use case, and then store that pre-calculated ranking. Stackoverflow does exactly that - if we were to look at your ranking on stackoverflow - https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2014-01-01/873641#873641 - this ranking is not being calculated dynamically. Your question has been upvoted so your reputation has increased by 5, but it's not reflected yet in your ranking.

A variation on this theme is to force a re-ranking whenever anyone's grade changes. Useful when the grade changes occur on some infrequent basis but by running the calculation right after the change you get minimal time when the ranking is off with minimal cost for constantly re-ranking.

Regarding the specifics of mongodb, yes you will need to walk the ranking list in order to calculate it.

Comment: I understand your point, but I think it does not remove the points stated above. Because after updating the grade of a student, you will have to update his ranking...and all others'. Of course, you can assume that after some accumulated grades, the rankings won't change much which each additional grade, and you could even allow for some error: like updating only one ranking at a time after a new grade is added without updating other's rankings.And I think thats the only possible solution with your approach...allowing for some error.

Comment: Yes that is correct, you will need to re-calculate all rankings after any grade change.